# Stop application getting notification from fcm/gcm

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I know some android app like chat applications use FCM or GCM from google services to send new messages notification to their users.

Now I want to know **there is any way from android devices setting to stop getting notifications** from FCM OR GCM .
Thanks.

Comment: Can't you subscribe to Firebase Topics? (If you're using Firebase)

Comment: I'm not using firebase . I want to know how stop firebase in android devices from setting. @Edric

Comment: Wait... You said you're not using Firebase, but you want to _stop firebase in android devices from setting_. What do you mean? Could you clarify?

Comment: I want to stop google service to stop all apps that use that service.

Answer (score 1):

**You can not stop FCM/GCM service only on your device.** but you can stop overall notifications of an app from `AppInfo` as shown below:

Go to **AppInfo > App Notifications**  and **turn off** the toggle to disable the notifications.

Below is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I want to stop FCM service not one app notification service.

Comment: Ok . Thanks VicJordan

Comment: new method here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/installations/FirebaseInstallations#delete()