# How does the reddit mobile app automatically update the recycler when a new message is sent? [GIF included]

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How does the reddit mobile app automatically update the recycler when a new message is sent?

https://i.imgur.com/qKWqf6S.mp4

Comment: take a look at how "Dank Reddit App" implements their message notification https://github.com/saket/Dank/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/saket/dank/notifs/CheckUnreadMessagesJobService.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is not very time critical, you can simply send notifications via [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). When a messages arrives, pass the message to your activity using listeners.

When a new message arrives, simply update the list you provided in the RecyclerView as data with the new message and then call `notifyDatesetChanged()` method or it's variations on the adapter from your host activity or fragment.

Comment: How do you listen for when a new message arrives?

Comment: @WHOATEMYNOODLES use socket for that. It will listen to the updates and you can create an interface to make an update to the recyclerview simply.

Comment: @WHOATEMYNOODLES there can a lot of solutions for that. it solely depends on your apps architecture and you backend solution. if your app is not time critical, you can simply use google's push notification. I've update my reply

Comment: Didn't think of using FCM which might be better solution than managing all the ws connections and creating a ws server

Comment: A single problem with the FCM is that it can be turned off from settings. If the notification is turned off, and the message still appears it means that it is not depends on that.

Comment: @barotia in android, any kind of background service can be turned off. but fcm is rather a safe bet. It is just a method of pushing the message, of course you must a backend that will host the actual notification and you have to check for updates time to time. if you need a much reliable option, there are plenty of solution that are both complex and time consuming to implement, firebase realtime db or firestore would be my choice then.

Comment: I do not think that a socket.IO or the firebase realtime database/firestorm is complex and/or time consuming to implement. Experience shows that in most of the cases the reliability is more important than the required time and complexity.

Comment: @barotia again, it depends. If it is your apps core functionality and/or your faster development is priority and/or developer experience. There is not "the" answer here.

Comment: Maybe the developer experience is the biggest factor here. And yeah, there is no "correct" answer, only good suggestions, cases.

Comment: @barotia Do you mean disable the reddit app notifications? Because according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165794/stop-application-getting-notification-from-fcm-gcm you cannot disable fcm

Comment: @WHOATEMYNOODLES you may not disable FCM notifications particularly, but, some mobile phone makers allow you to stop **all** background services to save power, as FCM depends on background services, it may misbehave if someone does that. but it is not official intended behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of socket, you can do real time updates. When ever the chat opens, the socket starts observing for changes and when change was detected it updates the recycler view and adapter was notified for the last position.

[Socket with chat and recycler view in android](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat)